# How can I use a display as a background in unity?

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript

I have a dancing game that I am trying to make and I have a stage where a character dances and a script to switch cameras inside that stage.
What I am trying to do is set those cameras to display 2 and use that display as a background for the place where the game actually takes place.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can set a Material as the result of the camera view, and then assign it to a plane.

Comment: I think more details needed. or a image.

Answer (score 1):

The way I achieved this is in a project consists of using an extended display configuration at operating system level. **Nvidia Mosaic** tool is great for this: I went up to 6 displays. You can then use a render-to-texture approach to render your camera onto a quad that corresponds to the area that is rendered to your 2nd display.

Also, it might be worth for you to have a look to how to launch a borderless window which I would recommend when using multiple displays. You do that by launching your Unity application with the popupwindow ([link 1](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html), [link 2](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html)) parameter. Fullscreen mode can be good too.